# Is it safe to drink tap water in Penang?

Tags: health, food-and-drink, malaysia, tap-water

I am just wondered whether is it safe to drink tap water in Penang?

Answer (score 4):

**Probably**, but most people (even locals) boil or filter it anyway, and many visitors opt to stick to bottled water.

As in many developing countries, water coming out of the treatment plant is safe, but the state of the plumbing between the plant and your hotel is often questionable.  For a short visit, it's probably not worth it to take the risk.